# regex optional group matching different sections of optional data

Tags: regex

I have the following type of data

```
Apple:Red
Kiwi:brown,Box:no
Grapes:"Black,Green",Box:yes,qty:55
```

I created this regex,

```
(.*):(.*)(?:(,)?),(Box):(.*),(qty):(.*)
```

but the issue is this matches only 3rd line.
first line has one set of data, second line has one comma and thrid line has two commas.  in other words, i have 3 sets of data and i need all the key and value in capture groups.  How can i make sections after each comma is optional, so that i can match all 3 lines?

Comment: Updated above, couldnt split (easily) as the values can itself contain comma.  is there a way to make regex match these groups optionally?

Comment: What about [`([^:\n]*):(.*?)(?:,Box:([^,\n]+)(?:,qty:(\d+))?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cI7koa/1)

Comment: @ctwheels matches only the 3rd line..  https://regex101.com/r/ZsCG3K/2

Comment: @SathishKumar did you even click on the link I provided? You need `m` flag. You can also use [`([^:\n]*):("[^"]*"|[^,\n]*)(?:,Box:([^,\n]+)(?:,qty:(\d+))?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cI7koa/2)

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks, didnt realize that was a link.  In my data i had space after the first :, anyways, your regex works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ctwheels Perhaps, you may write an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, must have overlooked the message the OP sent me. Added answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/cI7koa/4)

```
([^:\n]*):("[^"]*"|[^,\n]*)(?:,Box:([^,\n]+)(?:,qty:(\d+))?)?
```

- `([^:\n]*)` Capture any character except `:` or `\n` into capture group 1
- `:` Match this literally
- `("[^"]*"|[^,\n]*)` Capture either of the following into capture group 2

  - `"[^"]*"` Match `"`, then any character except `"` any number of times, then `"`
  - `[^,\n]*` Match any character except `,` or `\n` any number of times
- `(?:,Box:([^,\n]+)(?:,qty:(\d+))?)?` Optionally match the following

  - `,Box:` Match this literally
  - `([^,\n]+)` Capture any character except `,` or `\n` one or more times into capture group 3
  - `(?:,qty:(\d+))?` Optionally match the following

    - `,qty:` Match this literally
    - `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 4

Results in the following:

```
Apple
Red

Kiwi
brown
no

Grapes
"Black,Green"
yes
55
```